# Inserting null value without quotes

Tags: postgresql, php, null

I'm creating a PHP application which relies on PostgreSQL.
Now I have this query:

```
 $query= 'INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "username", "email", "phone") VALUES (\''. $name .'\', \''. $username .'\', \''. $email.'\', '. $phone .')';
```

`$email`, `$phone` and `$name` values can be null.

When I run this query, I get a syntax error.

So my question is: to insert a null value, I have to manually write null or am I missing something in the query?

Edit:
Seems like I am forced to write null as value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do **not** use this statement at all. You are wide open for SQL injection.
Use a **prepared statement** instead:

```
pg_prepare($pgconn, 'my_insert', "INSERT ... VALUES ($1, $2, ...)");
pg_query($pgconn, 'my_insert', array( $name, $username, ...));
```

The [PHP manual about `pg_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php):

> This function used to be called `pg_exec()`. `pg_exec()` is still
> available for compatibility reasons, but users are encouraged to use
> the newer name.

Related:

- [Using NULL value in INSERT or UPDATE with prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027549/939860)
- [How to convert empty to null in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035890/939860)

Comment: `pg_exec` has been replaced by `pg_query` and examples in official documentation references to `pg_execute` instead. Shouldn't this answer be updated?

Comment: @EAmez: Updated accordingly, thanks.